# How to multiple a value in Array of objects in java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is my array.

```
let menu = [
            { id: 1,  name: "Soda",price: 3.12,size: "4oz",type: "Drink" },
            { id: 2, name: "Beer", price: 6.50, size: "8oz", type: "Drink" },
            { id: 3, name: "Margarita", price: 12.99, size: "12oz", type: "Drink" },
            { id: 4, name: "Pizza", price: 25.10, size: "60oz", type: "Food" },
            { id: 5, name: "Kebab", price: 31.48, size: "42oz", type: "Food" },
            { id: 6, name: "Berger", price: 23.83, size: "99oz", type: "Food" }
        ]
```

I want to multiple prices in 1.8 and also double the sizes 
Then I want to show the main menu after these changes

This is my code and What I did.
This shows only prices and sizes, but I want the whole menu.

Code:

```js
let menu = [
        { id: 1,  name: "Soda",price: 3.12,size: "4oz",type: "Drink" },
        { id: 2, name: "Beer", price: 6.50, size: "8oz", type: "Drink" },
        { id: 3, name: "Margarita", price: 12.99, size: "12oz", type: "Drink" },
        { id: 4, name: "Pizza", price: 25.10, size: "60oz", type: "Food" },
        { id: 5, name: "Kebab", price: 31.48, size: "42oz", type: "Food" },
        { id: 6, name: "Berger", price: 23.83, size: "99oz", type: "Food" }
    ]

let prices = menu.map(item => item.price);
multipliedPrice = prices.map(item => (item * 1.8).toFixed(2));
//-------------------------------------------------------
doubledSize = menu.map(item => 2 * parseInt(item.size));

console.log("Size in USA is : " + doubledSize);
console.log("Price in USA is : " + multipliedPrice);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let prices = menu.map(item => { item.price = (item.price * 1.8).toFixed(2); return item;});
```

- If you just change the price as your need and return all item, you can display all your array items.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning the cacuated price only, return a new object like this:

```
menu.map(item => {
  return { ...item,
    price: 2 * parseInt(item.size)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this purpose, we'll multiply each price by 1.8 and then double the size of each item:

```js
let menu = [
            { id: 1,  name: "Soda",price: 3.12,size: "4oz",type: "Drink" },
            { id: 2, name: "Beer", price: 6.50, size: "8oz", type: "Drink" },
            { id: 3, name: "Margarita", price: 12.99, size: "12oz", type: "Drink" },
            { id: 4, name: "Pizza", price: 25.10, size: "60oz", type: "Food" },
            { id: 5, name: "Kebab", price: 31.48, size: "42oz", type: "Food" },
            { id: 6, name: "Burger", price: 23.83, size: "99oz", type: "Food" }
];

const newMenu = menu.map(item => { 
    return { ...item, price: item.price * 1.8, size: parseInt(item.size) * 2 + "oz" }
})

console.log("New menu:");
console.log("Item".padEnd(20) + "Size in USA".padEnd(20) + "Price in USA"); 
newMenu.forEach(item => console.log(item.name.padEnd(20) + (item.size + "").padEnd(20) + item.price.toFixed(2)))
```